# Python - send numpy.ndarray to weka package

Tags: python, weka

I tried to send a numpy object to Weka package using java bridge
but i got the below error.

`'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'jobject'`

what the best way to convert numpy.ndarray to jobject?